# dropwizard: Can I optionally map a parameter depending on it's presence in resultset?

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using Dropwizard 1.2.1 (I know a later version exists) for a project. What I have is a very common situation.

I have an app where a user signs up using his phone number. This creates an entry in my `user` table with just a phone number.

Now when the user logs in next, I want to retrieve the user details. This scenario is applicable for an existing user who has his/her other details (e.g first name) filled up already.

So my backend does a `select * from user where phoneNumber= <phoneNumber>` and the mapper tries to map the whole user object something like the following :

```
return new User(resultSet.getString("first_name"), resultSet.getString("middle_name"), resultSet.getString("last_name"), resultSet.getString("phone_number"), resultSet.getString("nationality"), resultSet.getString("mpin"));
```

Now the mapper naturally, in case of a fresh signup, would not find anything except the phoneNumber in the DB. So the rest of the `getString()` calls will fail. How do I avoid this and say `get whatever field is not null and form the object and return it to me`.

I see a documentation here for jdbi3 : http://jdbi.org/#_column_mappers but I am not sure if this will solve the problem. I haven't tried it yet as I am having some issues understanding it. So wanted a feedback if this is the right solution or is there another way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: I know there is a method `resultSet.findColumn('first_name')` that I can use to find if a column exists before trying to fetch it. But it will make this code pretty shitty looking if I start doing that for every field in the User mapper. Hence the effort to find a different solution.

Comment: If you read further in the JDBI3 manual you should notice the following: http://jdbi.org/#_constructormapper. At the end of the section there is the following text: 

By default, ConstructorMapper expects the result set to contain columns to map every constructor parameter, and will throw an exception if any parameters cannot be mapped.

Parameters annotated @Nullable may be omitted from the result set, in which ConstructorMapper will pass null to the constructor for that parameter.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for showing me this. I missed this in the doc completely.